# how to mount from /mnt/hgfs to desktop

Tags: mount, vmware, shared-folders

Host: win10 - Guest: Mint 19.1 - VMware Workstation: V15

shared folder on host is 'K:/Shared Folders'.
it is named 'Shared' in vm settings.

It shows up in '/mnt/hgfs/Shared' so I believe the installation is correct.

question is: What is the command to make a Link of it on the desktop or permanently mount it on a folder I created on the desktop named 'Shared'?

Comment: Using [ln](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ln)? `ln /mnt/hgfs/Shared /path/to/your/desktop/`

Comment: @ Mathieu it says : hard link not allowed for directory

Answer (score -1):

using ln -s and linking the rest worked. thanks.